# Why is Proposition 29 in Book I of Euclid‘s Elements dependent on the Parallel Postulate?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Proposition 29 says the following:

> *A straight line falling on parallel straight lines makes the alternate angles equal to one another*

Euclid proves this using the Parallel Postulate. I don’t understand why that’s necessary.
I can prove it without the postulate:

Let the straight line intersect the parallel straight lines in A and B. I claim that angle CAB= angle ABD.
Bisect AB in E and draw the circle with center E and A and B lying upon its circumference. The Circle intersects the straight parallel lines in F,A,B,G. Draw FG. Since angle AEF and angle BEG are vertical angles of two intersecting lines they are equal.
Since FE=AE=BE=DE and angle FEA=angle BEG we conclude that ΔFAE=ΔBGE and ΔFAE,ΔBGE are isosceles. Equal isosceles triangles have equal angles at their bases, so we have: angle FAE=angle EBG and thus: angle CAB=angle ABD

Can anybody help me understand it please? I’ve heard that Proposition 29 is the first one in Book I that is depending on the 5. Postulate and thus doesn’t hold in hyperbolic geometry.

[image]

Comment: How do you know that $FG$ intersects $AB$ at $E$?

Comment: To build on Aretino's comment: The reason why you "know" that FEG are colinear is because the alternating angles are the same. The problem you are trying to prove seems to be equivalent to $F,E,G$ being colinear.

Comment: Furthermore, if AB is *perpendicular* on the two lines, then F=A and G=B, and this degenerate case should be treated separately.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this theorem is not true because you have assumed that

> The Circle intersects the straight parallel lines in F,A,B,G. Draw FG.

and that F,E,G will be collinear but if you give a reason then this theorum might be true

credits to @Intelligenti pauca and @
N.S. in the comments

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it is cheating because it only recycles what has already been said in the comments.

Comment: i have given the credits is it ok now @AlexM.